# Debian package for kernel for the current machine?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I've a machine with all required *kernel configuration* changed and compiled.

I would like to create a *debian package* out of it so that I can use the same on other machines where I need to replicate the same configuration.

Is there a way?

If not, can I create a *debian kernel packages* along with *backports* of latest kernel?

-ram

Answer (score 0):

use `make-kpkg` from the `kernel-package` package to build a .deb

```
 make-kpkg --initrd kernel_image
```

this is all well covered in the [Debian FAQ](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-kernel.html)...